# Locating Files In Java Code

Tags: java, eclipse, file, embedded-resource

I'm trying to make a simple application that plays sounds. I have a sound file named sound.wav located in my java project (using eclipse btw). I am unsure of how to navigate to the sound file. The problem is that I don't know how to navigate through code to the sound file. What I'm running now throws a null pointer exception, ie. that file does not exist. Here is my code so far:

```
    private static Sound sound;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame j = new JFrame("Sound");
    j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    j.setSize(300, 150);
    sound = new Sound("/Users/Chris/Desktop/Workspace/Sound/sound.wav");
            //this is the problem line
    JButton play = new JButton("Play");
    play.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            sound.play();               
        }

    });

    j.add(play,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    j.setVisible(true);
}
```

Here is the code for my sound class:

```
    private AudioClip clip;

public Sound(String fileName) {
    try {
        clip = Applet.newAudioClip(Sound.class.getResource(fileName));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void play() {
    try {
        new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                clip.play();
            }
        }.start();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't help you until you tell us *what's wrong?*

Comment: And What's your problem ?

Answer (score 5):

`Class.getResource()`, as its javadoc indicates, reads resources from the classpath. Not from the file system.

Either you want to read from a file, and should use file IO (i.e. a `FileInputStream`), or you want to read from the classpath, and you should use `Class.getResource()` and pass a resource path, starting from the root of the classpath. For example, if sound.wav is in the runtime classpath, in the package `com.foo.bar.sounds`, the code should be

```
Sound.class.getResource("/com/foo/bar/sounds/sound.wav")
```

Comment: How would I go about getting the resource path to a file?

Comment: Read my answer. I completed it.

Comment: *"reads resources from the classpath. Not from the file system"*  There are situations where the file system *is* part of the run-time class-path.  But since most of these types of resources should be embedded, it is best to plan ahead and treat them as such from the start.